# How to add text to ggplot below the graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm looking at figures from Moreira et al. ([Nature, 2020](http://%20%20%5B1%5D:%20https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-020-2890-8)) where they have graphs indicating sample size and treatments under the barplots such as this:

[image: Moreira et al.]

Is there a way to reproduce this in ggplot? This would be very useful to indicate all the necessary information regarding an experiment in a compact manner.

Some dummy data for the plot:

```
library(tidyverse)

tibble(
  Rodent = c(rep("Mouse",11),
             rep("Hamster",7),
             rep("Guinea pig",4),
             rep("Gerbil",12)),
  `Weight (gm)` = rnorm(34,25,10),
  `Long whiskers` = c(rep("+",11),rep("-",7),rep("+",4),rep("-",12)),
  `Long tail` = c(rep("+",11),rep("-",7),rep("+",4),rep("-",12)),
  `Albino or normal` = c(rep("Albino",11),rep("Normal",7),rep("Albino",4),rep("Normal",12))
) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Rodent,`Weight (gm)`,fill = `Albino or normal`)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are probably two or three approaches to achieve your desired result. Personally I prefer to do it via `patchwork`, i.e create a second plot with the additional information you want to display and glue it to your main plot:

```r
library(tidyverse)

d <- tibble(
  Rodent = c(rep("Mouse",11),
             rep("Hamster",7),
             rep("Guinea pig",4),
             rep("Gerbil",12)),
  `Weight (gm)` = rnorm(34,25,10),
  `Long whiskers` = c(rep("+",11),rep("-",7),rep("+",4),rep("-",12)),
  `Long tail` = c(rep("+",11),rep("-",7),rep("+",4),rep("-",12)),
)

p1 <- d %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Rodent,`Weight (gm)`)) +
  geom_boxplot()

d1 <- d %>% 
  select(-`Weight (gm)`) %>%
  count(Rodent, `Long whiskers`, `Long tail`) %>% 
  distinct() %>% 
  mutate(n = as.character(n)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Rodent)

p2 <- d1 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Rodent, fct_rev(name), label = value)) +
  geom_text(size = 10) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank(), axis.text.x = element_blank())

library(patchwork)

p1 / p2
```

[image]

**EDIT** With a legend on the right it looks like so. I simply added a color legend where I mapped `Rodent` on `color`:

```r
p1 <- d %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Rodent,`Weight (gm)`, color = Rodent)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  theme(legend.position = "right")

p2 <- d1 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Rodent, fct_rev(name), label = value)) +
  geom_text(size = 10) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank(), axis.text.x = element_blank())

p1 / p2
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please add a possibility of doing the same when the upper plot has a legend on the right side? If there is a legend, the alignment is off!

Comment: Hi Anurag. I just made an edit and added a color legend to the upper plot. Hope I got you right.